# Why do translations and scaling behave as expected but rotation does not in a naive transform implementation?

Tags: matrix, graphics, 2d, transformation

I've been encountering an odd issue with manually applying transformation matrices to 2D points. When I apply a translation or scaling to the transformation matrix, the resulting location of 2D point is where one would expect it to be. Rotation, on the other hand, seems to skew and rotate the shape in odd and unexpected ways.

I've been trying to figure out why this issue is occurring for a couple of days, but to no avail. I've checked the mathematics and it doesn't seem to be the cause of the problem (the composite transformation behaves as expected when applied via the transform attribute in SVG, but not when manually applied to each pixel), so I'm lead to believe it's a flaw in my understanding of how transformation matrices are actually applied to 2D points. I'm naively multiplying the 2D point with the transformation matrix to get the new point.

Why isn't rotation behaving as expected?

An example that illustrates this issue is available on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dx4pLjgx/1/). Ignore the inverted y axis as the issue manifests itself even if a correctly oriented rotation matrix is used. Here is the main part:

```
window.onload = function(e) {
    var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];

    if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var ctm = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0];
        ctx.lineWidth = 0.0;

        function matrix_mul(a, b) {
            return [
                a[1]*b[2] + a[0]*b[0],
                a[1]*b[3] + a[0]*b[1],
                a[3]*b[2] + a[2]*b[0],
                a[3]*b[3] + a[2]*b[1],
                b[4] + a[5]*b[2] + a[4]*b[0],
                b[5] + a[5]*b[3] + a[4]*b[1]
            ];
        }
        function rotate(ang) {
            ctm = matrix_mul(ctm, [Math.cos(ang), Math.sin(ang), -Math.sin(ang), Math.cos(ang), 0.0, 0.0]);
        }
        function paint_point(x, y) {
            var x = ctm[0]*x + ctm[2]*y + ctm[4];
            var y = ctm[1]*x + ctm[3]*y + ctm[5];
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
        }
        function square() {
            for (i = 0; i <= 100; ++i) { paint_point(150+i, 150); }
            for (j = 0; j <= 100; ++j) { paint_point(150, 150+j);
                                         paint_point(250, 150+j); }
            for (i = 0; i <= 100; ++i) { paint_point(150+i, 250); }
        }


        square();
        for (d=0; d<3; ++d) {
            rotate(Math.PI/14);
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, ' + d+30*40 + ', 0)';
            square();
        }

        ctm = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0];
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 255)';
        rotate(Math.PI/14 * 3);
        square();

    } else {
        alert("Something bad happend");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a simple typo in your transform function

```
  function paint_point(x, y) {
    var x = ctm[0]*x + ctm[2]*y + ctm[4];
    var y = ctm[1]*x + ctm[3]*y + ctm[5];
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
  }
```

You have declared `x` and `y`, but they are already defined as arguments. Thus `x` is modified on the first line making the second line use the incorrect value of `x`.

Fix is simple.

```
  function paint_point(x, y) {
    var x1 = ctm[0]*x + ctm[2]*y + ctm[4];
    var y1 = ctm[1]*x + ctm[3]*y + ctm[5];
    ctx.fillRect(x1, y1, 1, 1);
  }
```

Or better

```
  function paint_point(x, y) {
    ctx.fillRect(
       ctm[0]*x + ctm[2]*y + ctm[4],
       ctm[1]*x + ctm[3]*y + ctm[5],
       1, 1
    );
  }
```

Comment: I've spent a couple of days reimplementing this little program in multiple languages and rendering it using multiple systems with the same issue cropping up every single time. I wouldn't have guessed that the issue was a simple bug as this. In hindsight, it should have been obvious. I can't thank you enough for pointing this out. I'll be accepting your answer tomorrow!

Comment: If you are happy with an answer, please consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..!